# Short story with a mirrored room and its owner can never turn around

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to find a story I read a few years ago, about a [psychomanteum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychomanteum) (a mirrored room). The story is told in the first person, and the (male) protagonist is there to interview someone about the room (I believe the owner had died). The bit I remember is the end, where it was something about the owner of the house/room "never turning around". It was really creepy and great and I can't remember for the life of me what it was called! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did the story involve a candle? Like the gentleman brought a single light source in with him to light the whole room and he was keeping watch for the man?

Comment: yes i think so!

Comment: did they use the term 'psychomanteum' in the story?

Comment: i'm pretty sure they used the word, and yes, there was a candle/single light source.

Answer (score 5):

The story is [Terry Dowling's](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?754) [*One Thing About the Night*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?309371).  I read it in [Ellen Datlow's](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?156) excellent short story collection [*The Dark: New Ghost Stories*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0091GTY5G).

Comment: ......you are possibly my most favorite person in the world right now, THANK YOU :D

Comment: A legal txt download of it is available [here](http://bookos.org/book/1797223/cb95c6).

I highly recommend all of his books, especially [Basic Black](http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Black-Terry-Dowling/dp/0980628822/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1368359094&sr=8-2&keywords=terry+dowling) and [Amberjack](http://www.amazon.com/Amberjack-Tales-Wonder-Terry-Dowling/dp/1596062932/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1368359094&sr=8-5&keywords=terry+dowling).

Amazing things about Dowling ar how good he is--and how unique his stories are.